# Having hard time placing a UIActivityIndicator inside a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview, addsubview

I am having some problems placing a UIActivityIndicator inside a UIButton.
Here is how it looks like:

[image]

And this is what i always get:

[image]

with this code:

```
  self.activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    CGFloat halfButtonHeight = self.updateEventButton.bounds.size.height / 2;
    CGFloat buttonWidth = self.updateEventButton.bounds.size.width;
    self.activityView.center = CGPointMake(buttonWidth - halfButtonHeight , halfButtonHeight);

    [self.subSubView addSubview:self.activityView];
    [self.activityView startAnimating];
```

I want the indicator to be in the buttom of the right corner. Just look where the indicator is right now and think if you dragged it down to the button and then a little to the right.

Here is how my view is setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating indicator position in coordinate system tied to the button, but then add it as a subview to the different view so coordinates are incorrect. To fix that you can add indicator view to the button directly:

```
[self.updateEventButton addSubview:self.activityView];
```

Or convert point in button's coordinate system to the coordinate system of `self.subSubView` before setting it to activityView:

```
CGPoint centerInButton = CGPointMake(buttonWidth - halfButtonHeight, halfButtonHeight);
self.activityView.center = [self.updateEventButton convertPoint:centerInButton
                                                         toView:self.subSubView];
```